# error to rosrun

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,i have an error to execute re_comm package and actually all packages in Roboearth Stack

i installed it in /home/marwa/ros and rosmake it

and i linked it with RoS

and bedin to roscore and run

but when typing : rosrun re_comm run

it makes error

```
rosrun] Couldn't find executable named run below /home/marwa/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_comm
```

the result of rosmake re_comm :

```
marwa@marwa-Inspiron-1564:~$ rosmake re_comm

[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['re_comm']                                 
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/marwa/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121118-143439
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['re_comm'] to:
['re_comm']                           
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rospack [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslib  No Makefile in package roslib                  
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslang  No Makefile in package roslang                
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< std_msgs  No Makefile in package std_msgs              
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rospack  No Makefile in package rospack                
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> thea [ make ]                                          
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp  No Makefile in package roscpp                  
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosjava_jni [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< geometry_msgs  No Makefile in package geometry_msgs    
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> re_msgs [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosbuild  No Makefile in package rosbuild              
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosprolog [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosjava_jni ROS_NOBUILD in package rosjava_jni         
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> jpl [ make ]                                           
[ rosmake ] All 9 linesthea: 2.4 sec ] [ re_msgs: ... [ 4 Active 8/50 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  cd jpl && autoconf
  sed 's/-cc-options\,//' jpl/configure > jpl/configure.sed; mv jpl/configure.sed jpl/configure; chmod +x jpl/configure
  if test -e /usr/lib/libswipl.so; then sed 's/-lpl/-lswipl/' jpl/configure > jpl/configure.sed; mv jpl/configure.sed jpl/configure; chmod +x jpl/configure; fi
  cd jpl && ./configure
  checking for swi-prolog... no
  checking for swipl... no
  checking for pl... no
  configure: error: "Cannot find SWI-Prolog. SWI-Prolog must be installed first"
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package jpl written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/marwa/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121118-143439/jpl/build_output.log
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< jpl [FAIL] [ 2.43 seconds ]                            
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package jpl. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< thea [PASS] [ 3.41 seconds ]                           
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosprolog [PASS] [ 3.43 seconds ]                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< re_msgs [PASS] [ 4.96 seconds ]                        
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 12 packages with 1 failures.                                  
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /home/marwa/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121118-14343
```

My bash file also :

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\\\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\\\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash


export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks:/home/marwa/ros
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48527/error-to-rosrun/) by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2012-11-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2012-11-18**:
@tbh  can u  help us in it plz ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error message indicates that

```
configure: error: "Cannot find SWI-Prolog. SWI-Prolog must be installed first"
```

That means you didn't install swi-prolog, after running

```
sudo apt-get install swi-prolog
```

rosmake re_comm again.

---

Originally posted by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) with karma: 1371 on 2012-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-18**:
json_prolog is part of the knowrob stack. I would suggest to not install it from souce anyway but with `sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-knowrob`. That will pull in all required dependencies, including swi-prolog.